# Windows phone Silverlight 8.1: Can't create app package

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create app package with CameraSampleCS from [Windows Phone 8.1 samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7)
But when I opened Project > Store, there was only 1 option: Launch Windows App Certification Kit. I ran it, project passed and nothing more.
Here is a picture:

[image]

Is there anything wrong with this project because when I tried another one, I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, the project which cannot be packaged is a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. As far as I know, Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight is still using the ".xap" file as the packaged app, same with Windows phone 8, so it may not need to launch the "Create app packages" like the WP8.1 Runtime. You should find your package in the Debug/Release folders.